# How can I store user API tokens for app in AWS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, api-design

Developing app where end users (e.g. developers) may use tokens to initiate an action in the app. Users would generate / revoke the token within the web app itself... a very common pattern.

Users may use the token programmatically schedule an action, or even integrate it into some other process (e.g. code builds, etc).

Using AWS as cloud provider, I'm thinking of storing info in DynamoDB as key / value pair (e.g. API token and user id, respectively).

Tell me why this is bad idea, and please offer alternatives.
(*AWS KMS seems overkill, and Secrets Manager has quota limits.*)

Comment: Sorry for my question, but a token is something that changes IN the code? Or is it like an environment variable? For parameters that don't change a lot like API keys we use https://docs.aws.amazon.com/es_es/systems-manager/latest/userguide/sysman-paramstore-walk.html

Comment: Think like how you get a API token from Github (if you're familiar with that). User will create a token, which app will store. User will use token to send data to app, and maybe read data from app. If user is now longer using the token, they can "revoke" it

Comment: For now, the token will not allow any "destructive" or "overwritting" actions. Only writes new data that will be associated with user account, and maybe allow user to read data using the token.

Comment: Well, in this case, I think Dynamo DB is a good idea, it is fast and easy to use. Maybe you can save the token encrypted in Dynamo, using for example an AWS KMS key. Secrets Manager is more for DB secrets, and it is not cheap

Comment: Ya, I wish there was a more straight forward solution. Using DynamoDB seems like a lot of extra code that I have to write.